# How to get all strings inside [...] in one NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

Say given an NSString:

```
@"[myLabel]-10-[youImageView]"
```

I need an array of:

```
@[@"myLabel", @"yourImageView"]
```

How do I do it?

I thought about going through the string and check each '[' and ']', get string inside them, but is there any other better way?

Thanks

Comment: How about `NSDictionary *constrainedViews = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(myLabel, yourImageView)`?

Comment: Regular expressions will probably be a good choice here. See `NSRegularExpression`.

Comment: Your key/value is always separated by "-10-" const string ?

Comment: Hi, I just need to get all strings in all [] pair, they do may not be separated by -10-

Comment: @hzxu Follow-up for Mike's suggestion, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668877/unable-to-extract-string-using-nsregularexpression-regex-pattern-iphone) looks related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions:

```
NSString *string = @"[myLabel]-10-[youImageView]";

// Regular expression to find "word characters" enclosed by [...]:
NSString *pattern = @"\\[(\\w+)\\]";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                                       options:0
                                     error:NULL];

NSMutableArray *list = [NSMutableArray array];
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:string
            options:0
              range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])
             usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
                 // range = location of the regex capture group "(\\w+)" in the string:
                 NSRange range = [result rangeAtIndex:1];
                 [list addObject:[string substringWithRange:range]];
             }
 ];
NSLog(@"%@", list);
```

Output:

```
(
    myLabel,
    youImageView
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
NSCharacterSet *aSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"]-10["];
NSArray *anArray = [aString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:aSet];
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not work, the [] pairs are separated by random things, not necessarily be -10-